# Stored collection for multiple itemviews: marionette

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js, marionette

I have a composite view called QueueItems, and then a itemView for each of them in the collection that will let me modify each of those elements.  Each element needs to be able to select from multiple tag collections, e.g. States, Companies, etc.  The problem is that I am not sure how to embed this into the individual item views.  I don't want to make a call each time there is an itemView, so I placed the collection in the composite view.  But there comes my problem in that I don't know how to access it, and if I did, how to determine if the ajax to pull the collection had success.

Thoughts, suggestions; anything is helpful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can store the collections in a globally accessible location. I have seen people attach them to their Application object when bootstrapping their application.

```
App.States = new StatesCollection();
App.States.fetch();
```

If you have created this collection in your CompositeView object, then you can pass it to each child using the childViewOptions parameter.

```
var QueueItems = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
  childViewOptions: {
    states: this.states
  },

  initialize: function() {
     this.states = new StatesCollection();
     this.states.fetch();
  }
}
```

You can then just grab it in the childView initialize.

```
var QueueItem = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  initialize: function(options) {
    this.states = options.states;
  }
}
```

As far as worrying about whether they are loaded or not, you should just add a listener to your ItemView to render anytime the collection is synced or reset. Then it will just re-render itself anytime you fetch or load the collection.

```
var QueueItem = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  initialize: function(options) {
    this.states = options.states;
    this.listenTo(this.states, 'sync reset', this.render);
  }
}
```